# Check which AWS availability zones can spin up a P2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Is there a way to add a filter or something to the `aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region us-east-1` command so that it only returns AZs in which I can spin up a P2.2xlarge instance.

Comment: There is no single CLI command to achieve what you want. It is possible by combining using the results of `describe-availability-zones` in `describe-reserved-instances-offerings`. Can be easily done using `boto3`

Comment: `describe-reserved-instances-offerings` might not a reliable means of determining whether an instance is available -- there are some instances in some regions that can be launched, but are not available as Reserved Instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like there is no way to do this through the CLI.

I opened a support case with AWS and they verified that you cannot do this at this time :(